# ionic TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap

i installed ionic + cordova by ionic site document

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

after install finished i run ionic commands ... but not work ionic !

i get error :

```
    C:\Users\Administrator>ionic info
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:186:7)
    at Project.BaseConfig (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\config.js:27:30)
    at Project (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\no
de_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\project.js:25:1)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\dist\index.
js:54:25
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\
dist\index.js:4:58)
```

pleas help me i searched very more in google but not found solution : (

system info :

```
    windows 7
node js 6
npm 3
sdk android installed + path 
java installed + path
apache ant installed + path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved by

step 1 :

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

step 2 :

```
npm install -g ionic@canary
```